# Custom Data Validation Annotations - ASP.NET MVC2 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I have a viewmodel that partially looks like this...

```
        [Required]
        public int Year { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1, 5000000)]
        public int ModelID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ZipCode{ get; set;}
```

I want to add a custom validator attribute that checks a database to make sure the Zip is valid.  Something like...

```
        [Required]
        [IsValidZipcode]
        public int ZipCode{ get; set;}
```

I haven't been able to find a tutorial on the net - I don't think I know what to search for because this seems like it would be common.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a class which inherits from the ValidationAttribute class, ovveriding the IsValid method:

```
public class IsValidZipCode: ValidationAttribute
{
   public override bool IsValid(object value)
   {
      return db.ValidateSomething(value);
   }
}
```

Then you're good to go:

```
[IsValidZipCode(ErrorMessage = "Not a valid zip code!")]
public int ZipCode { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You extend `ValidationAttribute` as shown in [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx). `ValidationAttribute` has a method IsValid() which you can override to indicate the model's validity.

Comment: +1 to you for not getting a vote, even though you beat me by 30 seconds. :)

Comment: Hehe, thanks. Your answer was better - people don't like to read :D

Comment: I didn't notice you were first.  But yea.. Copy + Pasting is way easier. +1